# Markers and Windows(Angular google maps) not working after upgrade to angular 1.3.8

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

I have been using angular-google-maps for sometime. I have not faced any major issues till now. But one of my colleagues had upgraded angular to 1.3.8 recently. And since then I am getting the following errors while instantiating the  and  directives and I do not see any markers. Here are the errors I get. Any inputs or directions to debug will be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Here is the first error:

```
Error: this.mapCtrl.getMap is not a function
this.MarkersParentModel</MarkersParentModel.prototype.createMarkers@http://localhost/scripts/1b3f05c4.modules.js:2637:75
__bind/<@http://localhost/scripts/1b3f05c4.modules.js:2569:16
this.MarkersParentModel</MarkersParentModel.prototype.onTimeOut@http://localhost/scripts/1b3f05c4.modules.js:2612:16
__bind/<@http://localhost/scripts/1b3f05c4.modules.js:2569:16
__bind/<@http://localhost/scripts/1b3f05c4.modules.js:2234:16
IMarkerParentModel/<@http://localhost/scripts/1b3f05c4.modules.js:2290:11
timeout/timeoutId<@http://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16205:28
completeOutstandingRequest@http://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4902:7
Browser/self.defer/timeoutId<@http://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5282:7
http://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.js
Line 11594
```

And here is the second error:

```
Error: this.linked.ctrls[0].getMap is not a function
this.WindowsParentModel</WindowsParentModel.prototype.createChildScopesWindows@http://localhost/scripts/1b3f05c4.modules.js:2860:21
__bind/<@http://localhost/scripts/1b3f05c4.modules.js:2726:16
WindowsParentModel/<@http://localhost/scripts/1b3f05c4.modules.js:2785:18
timeout/timeoutId<@http://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16205:28
completeOutstandingRequest@http://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4902:7
Browser/self.defer/timeoutId<@http://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5282:7
http://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.js
Line 11594
```

Line 2860:

```
var markersScope, modelsNotDefined, _this = this;
    this.isIconVisibleOnClick = true;
    if (angular.isDefined(this.linked.attrs.isiconvisibleonclick)) {
      this.isIconVisibleOnClick = this.linked.scope.isIconVisibleOnClick;
    }
    >>>> this.gMap = this.linked.ctrls[0].getMap();
    markersScope = this.linked.ctrls.length > 1 && this.linked.ctrls[1] != null ? this.linked.ctrls[1].getMarkersScope() : void 0;
    modelsNotDefined = angular.isUndefined(this.linked.scope.models);
    if (modelsNotDefined && (markersScope === void 0 || markersScope.markerModels === void 0 && markersScope.models === void 0)) {
      this.$log.info('No models to create windows from! Need direct models or models derrived from markers!');
      return;
    }
```

Line 2637:

```
this.gMarkerManager = new directives.api.managers.MarkerManager(this.mapCtrl.getMap());
```

Comment: This is pretty difficult to debug. I'd suggest looking at where this.mapCtrl, this.linked, and this.linked.ctrls are initialized. Log them out and see why they dont have the getMap fn.

Comment: Try putting together a minimal example of failing code and provide that code on a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/).

Comment: So do you mean that you are using the exactly same code that you used to use for previous version of Angular JS and its not working for 1.3.8? If this is the case than is the compatibility issue of new version, but if the code is changed than its a coding issue.